# yacc parser reduces before left recursion suffix

Tags: c, parsing, yacc, lalr

I wrote a pretty simple left-recursive grammar in yacc, based on data types for a simple C-like language. The generated yacc parser reduces before the left recursion suffix, and I have no clue why.

Here is the source code:

```
%%
start: type {
        printf("Reduced to start.\n");
    };

type: pointer {
        printf("Reduced pointer to type.\n");
    } 
    | char {
        printf("Reduced char to type.\n");
    };

char: KW_CHAR {
        printf("Reduced to char.\n");
    };

pointer: type ASTERISK {
        printf("Reduced to pointer.\n");
    };
%%
```

Given the input `char *` (KW_CHAR ASTERISK):

```
Reduced to char.
Reduced char to type.
syntax error
```

Comment: I think you have something wrong with your source code beyond the grammar, or that you didn't build it right. It's hard to say because not enough is shown. Filling in the details, it works fine for me.

Comment: Most likely a lexer problem -- perhaps the space is causing problems.  Try running with YYDEBUG enabled (set `yydebug = 1;` before calling `yyparse();`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be asking about the parse error you're receiving (which, as noted in the comments, is likely an issue with the token types being returned by `yylex()`), but rather why the parser reductions are performed in the order shown by your trace. That's the question I will try to address here, even though it's quite possible that it's an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), because understanding reduction order is important.

In this case, the reduction order is pretty simple. If you have a production:

```
pointer: type ASTERISK
```

then `type` must be reduced before `ASTERISK` is shifted. In an LR parser, reductions must be done when the right-hand side to be reduced ends exactly at the last consumed input token. (The lookahead token has been identified by the lexical scanner but not yet consumed by the parser. So it's not part of the reduction and can be used also to identify other reductions ending at the same point.)

I hope it's more evident why with the production

```
type: char
```

`char` needs to be reduced before `type`. Until `char` is reduced, it's not available to be used in the reduction of `type`.

Really, these two examples show the same behaviour. Reductions are performed left-to-right, and from the bottom up (that is, children first). Hence the name for this kind of parsing.

So the reduction order shown by your parser (first `char`, then `type`, and only after the `*` is shifted, `pointer`) is precisely what would be expected.

Comment: Thank you. It was a lexer problem, however I didn't understand the parsing sufficiently, so I thought it was a parser problem.